# Blazor 0.6.0 "wipes" Flurl-compatibility?

Tags: flurl, blazor, httpclientfactory

After updating Blazor from 0.5.1 (with working Flurl) to 0.6.0, calls via flurl throw an exception:

```
WASM: [Flurl.Http.FlurlHttpException] Call failed. Cannot invoke method 
because it was wiped. See stack trace for details.
```

The project creates a HttpClientFactory which gets Blazor's HttpClient for being used by Flurl:

Create FlurlClient with Blazor's HttpClient (http) using HttpClientFactoryForBlazor:

```
IFlurlClient c = new FlurlClient() { Settings = new Flurl.Http.Configuration.ClientFlurlHttpSettings { HttpClientFactory = new HttpClientFactoryForBlazor(http) }};
```

Use the FlurlClient (c) for example by via Flurl's extensionmethod "IFlurlRequest.WithClient(c);"

```
private class HttpClientFactoryForBlazor : Flurl.Http.Configuration.IHttpClientFactory
{
    private readonly HttpClient httpClient;

    public HttpClientFactoryForBlazor(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        this.httpClient = httpClient;
    }

    public virtual HttpClient CreateHttpClient(HttpMessageHandler handler)
    {
        return this.httpClient;
    }
}
```

So, it seems like this approach does no longer work.

Does anybody know how to make Flurl with Blazor 0.6.0 work?

Call-Stack is:

```
WASM: [Flurl.Http.FlurlHttpException] Call failed. Cannot invoke method because it was wiped. See stack trace for details. GET http://srv01.servicegrid.eu:4455/API/Status?forceLoadDbs=False blazor.webassembly.js:1:32098
WASM:   at Flurl.Http.FlurlRequest.HandleExceptionAsync (Flurl.Http.HttpCall call, System.Exception ex, System.Threading.CancellationToken token) <0x26945b8 + 0x001c2> in <c38761af4558433f81b1691eb86a1548>:0 blazor.webassembly.js:1:32098
WASM:   at Flurl.Http.FlurlRequest.SendAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpMethod verb, System.Net.Http.HttpContent content, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken, System.Net.Http.HttpCompletionOption completionOption) <0x2665d30 + 0x005e6> in <c38761af4558433f81b1691eb86a1548>:0 blazor.webassembly.js:1:32098
WASM:   at Flurl.Http.FlurlRequest.SendAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpMethod verb, System.Net.Http.HttpContent content, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken, System.Net.Http.HttpCompletionOption completionOption) <0x2665d30 + 0x0079a> in <c38761af4558433f81b1691eb86a1548>:0 blazor.webassembly.js:1:32098
WASM:   at Flurl.Http.HttpResponseMessageExtensions.ReceiveJson[T] (System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] response) <0x26a2180 + 0x000d6> in <c38761af4558433f81b1691eb86a1548>:0 blazor.webassembly.js:1:32098
WASM:   at DotNetFabrik.FlurlExtensions.FlurlRequestExtensions.HandleWebApiExceptions[T] (System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] task) <0x26a43f8 + 0x000e2> in <8c1e6df9d3f545cd831ff49915df2d85>:0 blazor.webassembly.js:1:32098
WASM:   at DotNetFabrik.FlurlExtensions.FlurlRequestExtensions.HandleWebApiExceptions[T] (System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] task) <0x26a43f8 + 0x00264> in <8c1e6df9d3f545cd831ff49915df2d85>:0 blazor.webassembly.js:1:32098
WASM:   at BlazorCoreDMSTools.CommunicationService.CommunicationService.SetTokenAsync (System.String token, System.String database, System.String serverUri) <0x260dc60 + 0x00d9e> in <cb925648b50340888772566fbaeac465>:0
```

Comment: Could you provide the call stack for the exception? I might need to see exactly where it threw in order to provide an effective fix/work-around.

Comment: @ToddMenier Added the call stack. Hope, you find a solution - Blazor and Flurl are both great tools and did fine teamwork in the last months.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just for some background, the Blazor team is in the process of significantly reducing the app's footprint, and resorting to some [unusual measures](https://github.com/aspnet/Blazor/pull/1382) to do so. In a nutshell, they've reduced it by about 20% by "wiping" `HttpClientHandler`.

> *wipe* means "replace specified method bodies with a single throw
>   instruction". Doing this (instead of actually removing the method
>   entirely) means that the assembly retains a completely standard API
>   surface, and if you try to use one of the wiped methods, you get an
>   easy-to-understand exception stack trace that tells you which wiped
>   method you're trying to call.

This is what you've bumped up against: Blazor is still aware of `HttpClientHandler` for compilation purposes, but will throw a runtime exception if you (or in this case a compatible library) try to use it.

But `HttpClient` must wrap *some* implementation of `HttpMessageHandler` Blazor has its own: [`BrowserHttpMessageHandler`](https://github.com/aspnet/Blazor/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Browser/Http/BrowserHttpMessageHandler.cs). And Flurl provides an easy way to swap this in via its [`HttpClientFactory`](https://flurl.dev/docs/configuration/#httpclientfactory). But you don't need to pass in an `HttpClient` instance or implement `CreateHttpClient`. Instead, inherit from `DefaultHttpClientFactory` and just override `CreateMessageHandler`:

```
private class HttpClientFactoryForBlazor : DefaultHttpClientFactory
{
    public override HttpMessageHandler CreateMessageHandler()
    {
        return new BrowserHttpMessageHandler();
    }
}
```

I'd also recommend registering this once globally on app startup, rather than every time you create a `FlurlClient`:

```
FlurlHttp.Configure(settings =>
{
    settings.HttpClientFactory = new HttpClientFactoryForBlazor();
});
```

It should also be noted that Blazor is still experimental and that [`BrowserHttpMessageHandler` may be deprecated in a future release](https://github.com/aspnet/Blazor/issues/1484#issuecomment-424763057), so expect that this could be just a temporary work-around.

Comment: Yikes. I'm not sure what the point is of maintaining an "API surface" that doesn't function.  I would rather "target" and get get errors in the IDE rather than this.  I really hope blazor succeeds but stuff like this is concerning.

Comment: `BrowserHttpMessageHandler` "now" (https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/commit/ceb1c8e562562b2655622b571d2a9ad083806ad5 ) is named `WebAssemblyHttpMessageHandler`. Still works with the code above when replaced.

Comment: I have applied the above fix, it works on a mocky test, but when I try it on azure function with headers, it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Currently in my 3.0 preview 5, `BrowserHttpMessageHandler` is not there anymore. Here is my current fix by simply not using any `HttpMessageHandler`. As far as I am aware, no problem happens to me yet, but I am not sure in all use cases:

```
class BlazorHttpClientFactory : DefaultHttpClientFactory
{

    public override HttpClient CreateHttpClient(HttpMessageHandler handler)
    {
        return new HttpClient();
    }

    public override HttpMessageHandler CreateMessageHandler()
    {
        return null;
    }

}
```